# Does it makes sense that my main character is not going to solve the plot's main objective?

Tags: characters, novel

*First of all, sorry, english is not my mother tongue*

My novel runs on a sci-fi universe and my main character (MC) has been infected by a virus that infects others that breathes the same air.

Synthesizing the virus antitoxin is the main objective of the plot. But he would need to move from one planet to another in order to find the scientific that is able to create the antitoxin for him.

How could I make him (MC) to go from one planet to another without infecting all people around him?

Would it makes more sense that he (MC) order someone else to find the antitoxin and send it to him?

Please, feel free to post any idea you may have to help me with this!! :)

Comment: "How ... without infecting" is one question, and "order someone else" is another, which may make your book look like "Lord of the Rings" from Gandalf's perspective.

Comment: Yeap, that's my doubt... I dont know how to proceed either to find a way to send the MC through several planets to reach the scientist or either find someone else to do the job for him. What would you think about pros and cons of both options? May you have another proposal to get the antitoxin?

Comment: Think what's your book is going to be about. If it's about hero's journey, you have to find a way to send MC in person. If the book is about a plague, and how the cure is found is not really relevant, you can send someone else.

Comment: Many thanks Alexander! I will rethink the core message of the book :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that my reply is not likely the answer you're looking for, but still, I thought it could be useful for someone.

I immediately thought of 'the hero story' vs. 'the villain story', and in your case, the character that you call MC could easily be the person that everyone else sees as the villain - Hear me out;

If he does try to solve the issue himself (maybe he already failed at getting help from more powerful people), he might do it to save not only himself but also his family and friends - they are probably infected too. To most people, this will be an understandable reason for doing something, but the reader might not learn this reason at first.

If, then, you have another character, who doesn't know the original MC, who lives on this planet. This other character could have connections to the scientist/scientists who could help solve the issue. What this/these character(s) will then experience is a random person coming to their planet, infecting civilians while demanding the attention of acclaimed scientists, perhaps with trouble describing why.

When this happens, your other character might witness this or hear about it, and learn that the scientists refuse to meet a stranger's demands, after which the 'MC' feels forced to kidnap the scientists or hold them hostage in the building of their sciences.

Perhaps your other character is then captured in the same building and feels the need to 'save' their coworkers (the scientists), and that is how the story "begins"...

That other character could very well be the first to realize that 'the MC' is not actually a villain. After all, very few villains see themselves as a bad guy.

Just an idea.

Comment: OOOOOOMMMMMMGGGGGG!!! AWESOME idea!!! Many thanks @Storbror :) Very very interesting point of view.

Comment: I'm glad you like it. Good luck with your writing!

Answer (score 1):

You say sci-fi but don't state an allowable level of technology. If your MC's physical body is restrained in an airtight isolation ward, is there any chance they could be neurally interfaced to an avatar that acts as their physical representation out in the world? If the MC is going to need to travel to other star systems then the underlying technology would need to involve faster than light communications, but if that's allowable within your world it could allow you to send the MC forth without risking the people he meets. To add to the sense of risk you could invoke a Matrix-style mechanism that if the remote avatar 'dies' it results in some kind of massive neural feedback that would actually kill your MC too.

You might find it beneficial to post a related question in the Worldbuilding SE to ask about how you might solve the technological aspects.

Comment: Very helpful!! I will take all of these info into account and think about the technological level.

Comment: By the way, I like the idea of the avatar!